# Touchpad Scrolling not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hp, scrolling, mouse-scroll, hp-touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on VM-ware workstation 14 pro. HP 2000 2d29tu is my laptop and my touch-pad scrolling is not working.
My touchpad is working, but only single touch left click and right click is working.

I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't know about how to enable the scroll settings.

[image]

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse           id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vmware doesn't support touchpad scrolling.

- You can ether us VirtualBox
- or try to follow [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/131297/use-synaptics-touchpad-scroll-in-vmware-guest/683726#683726)
- or you are brave and get [support from VMware](https://www.vmware.com/company/contact/contactus.html?department=prod_request)

Comment: I dont use vmware, which solution worked?

Comment: Previously I used Vmware. then I installed VirtualBox as you told. Then it worked.